# Unable to activate Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-activation

I had to reset my Windows 8 laptop to factory settings because an application downloaded from the Microsoft official page totally ruined the OS and now I cannot activate Windows. When I enter product code in an elevated command prompt I receive a WindowsScriptHost error:

> "Run slui.exe on a computer running Microsoft Windows non-core edition 
>    0x2a 0x80070426 to display the error text".

Google told me to check for Software Protection service - when I try to start it, I get: Error 5-access denied, although I am administrator.

Can anyone please help - there must be a solution other than formatting? I am using Windows 8.1 64b on Dell Inspiron laptop.

Comment: You may have disk corruption, run a chkdsk /r on the drive.

Comment: Make and model of Laptop, and exactly how you restored it please.

Comment: Similar issue on W7....http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/229686-not-genuine-messages-error-0x80070426.html

Comment: First of all, thank you for your replies.
Here is specification: http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-3542-laptop_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf
ServiceTag (number issued by Dell to identify their devices) is:GY0S812 Reset was made by using system-built in Windows8 feature (it started automatic repair which failed and I was presented with a few options to select from), at that stage it was not more possible to access computer in conventional way. I already made such reset over a year ago, when Windows Updates (another great invention from

Comment: I'd post a comment if it allowed me to do so.
The error when starting service is the same as mentioned in my first post "Error 5: access denied". I have write access to Windows\System32 folder.
Just tried to start the service on another user account with admin rights - same.
Is the problem unresolvable?

Comment: Please stop posting comments as answers and get your accounts merged already. ;) — It sounds like your Windows installation is terribly broken. You should perform a clean installation.

Comment: @Damian you cannot comment on this question because you you originally posted the question using an unregistered account. You need to either go back to the computer you originally posted the question from, potentially creating your account properly from that machine, or you need to use the [contact](http://superuser.com/contact) form to ask for your two accounts to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

The error `0x80070426` means `ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE - The service has not been started`. Run the services MMC snapin (services.msc) as admin (rightclick and select run as admin) and make sure the  Software Protection service is not configured as disabled. Set it to automatic and start the service.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reinitializing the slui activation system - Press `windows+R` and type `slui 3` into the run bar.  This will allow you to run activation again and reenter your activation code.

However, since your system reset did not complete properly, the problems you are seeing are probably a result of a corrupt or failed installation.  I recommend you do a clean installation of Windows 8.

You can download Windows 8 or 8.1 from Windows legally as long as you have a genuine product key.  Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows8 and download the media creation tool + ISO (if you cannot download through this website then let me know and I will direct you to other links).  You will have to do this from a friend's computer.  Remember to backup all your files before formatting the drive.

Once you have gone through the whole process of installing, Windows should activate automatically.  However, if it does not activate automatically, press `windows+R` and type `slui 3` into the run bar.  This will allow you to run activation again.